# Dynamic list of property names for SPE report

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to run a script to extract Sitecore item data. As of now if I use the below script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path master:/Sitecore/content/Data -Recurse |Show-ListView -Property DisplayName, ItemPath,TemplateName,Language,"Field1","Field2","Field3"
```

It gives the data in the table and the value of Field1,Field2 and Field3 are also populated for each item.

In this scenario I have to manually find all the fields in item and child item and place them in script like Field1, Field2, Field3 to get their values.

Is there a way I can get the fields from item template and use it in script instead of manually mentioning Field1,Field2,Field3

Comment: With Show-ListView you can omit the Property parameter.to get all properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the item template fields dynamically using this way.

```
# Get the item children
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path master:/Sitecore/content/Home -Recurse 

# Create a loop on each item 
foreach($item in $items) 
{
    # Get the item template of the item
    $itemTemplate = Get-ItemTemplate $item

    # Get fields 
    $itemTemplateFields = $itemTemplate.OwnFields | Select-Object -ExpandProperty key -Unique 
    $fields =[System.String]::Join(",", ($itemTemplateFields | Where-Object { $standardFields -notcontains $_ } | Sort-Object)) 

    # You will get the field name in a string with a comma-separated value.
    Write-Host $fields
}
```

Use this in your logic and it will work.

Also to use this variable called `$fields`, you need to create a dynamic query and then use `Invoke-Expression` to execute this.

```
$query = "Get-ChildItem -Path master:/sitecore/content/Home |Show-ListView -Property DisplayName, ItemPath,TemplateName,Language," + $fields

Invoke-Expression $query
```

Thanks

Comment: When i am trying to add this $fields in the below query :
Get-ChildItem -Path master:/Sitecore/content/Data -Recurse |Show-ListView -Property DisplayName, ItemPath,TemplateName,Language,$fields. 

 It Fails. Tried Foreach Object,that also not working.Need the individual fields append to the query GetChildItem

Comment: @Debaparna Updated my answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to the item fields

```
$hashTable = @{} 
Get-ChildItem $rootItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $currentItem = $_
    $inheritedFields = "";
    Get-ItemField -Item $currentItem -ReturnType Field -Name "*" `
    | Where-Object {$_.ContainsStandardValue} | Select-Object -Property Name,Value `
    | ForEach-Object{ $inheritedFields += ("[" + $_.Name + ": " + $_.Value + "]")}
    if($inheritedFields -ne "")
    {
        $hashTable.Add($currentItem.ContentPath, $inheritedFields)
    }
}

$hashTable | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You will get output in `table format`, I tested it on my `Sitecore instance`.